# Random UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: vb.net, io

I have something similar:

```
    System.IO.File.Delete(_save_file_dialog.FileName)

    ...

    _sw = New StreamWriter(filename)
    _sw.Write(_data.ToString)
    _sw.Close()
```

The delete works, the FileDialog doesn't find any readonly problem. But once in a while (randomly) StreamWrite throws an UnauthorizedAccessException.
This is on a network drive.

We just recently switched from XP to Win7, the problem never happen on XP.

Is it possible that the Delete might not be finished after calling it?

Comment: Without more of your code or more information on your error, there isn't much that i can see that can be figured out.